# Using IPs for websites also for their name servers

Tags: ip, vps, nameserver, host

My new web hosting company (managed VPS) suggests I use the two IPs assigned to my websites as the name servers for those same sites. (One IP is dedicated to one site, the other IP will be shared among several sites.) I've not yet taken my sites live, and I hesitate to re-point my "live" website names to my new IPs. Sorry - I'm a noob. For 15 years I've hosted my busy sites on shared servers where the hosting co assigned NS1 and NS2, and I'm trying hard to graduate and move up to VPS.

Should I do what they're suggesting? They're telling me to use the 2 IPs as NS1 and NS2 for all my domains that will be hosted on the server.

I've researched this on serverfault and elsewhere, and it's pretty clear that the advice is to use different name servers on other networks. I've asked my new host to explain this but I'd love to hear from anyone who thinks this is an acceptable practice. (I realize no one can explain my host's approach!)

Thanks for comments and advice!

Answer (score 1):

Most domain name registrars will host some DNS records for you.

Unless you make a lot of changes to the records and want to use your own control panel, custom scripts or hand editing of configuration files you are better off using your registrar's DNS servers and hosting the records there.

Your host likely defaults to having you use their name servers so their control panel can be used to manage your DNS records. If you use your registrar's instead then you would manage the entries using the control panel provided by the registrar.